# How to drop MKAnnotation Pin one by one?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Need to drop annotation one by one into map... Even drop annotation pin from left to right. Is there a method to make annotation drop more stylish and simple

```
func addannotaiton(){
    sistermaplist.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    sistermaplist.removeAnnotations(sistermaplist.annotations)
    var i = 0
    let count = mapsisterarray.count
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.5,1.5)
    while (i != count ) {

        let mbr = mapsisterarray[i]

        if mbr.lat != "",mbr.lon != ""{
        let latitude  = Double((mbr.lat  ?? "0.0")!)
        let longitude = Double((mbr.lon ?? "0.0")!)

        let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        sistermaplist.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = mbr.name ?? ""

        annotation.subtitle = mbr.meet_place ?? ""

        sistermaplist.addAnnotation(annotation)



    }
        i += 1
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by dropping an MKAnnotation pin?  In English, it sounds more like you want to remove one.  Yet, your code suggests that you are adding one.

Comment: Annotation is normally animated as a drop on to map .. that's what I meant by dropping annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over animation I would suggest you to do it yourself. You can subclass `MKAnnotationView` and add your pin to it as a subview. Then animate the pin to drop whenever and however you wish.

This being said I would add all of the annotations to the view at the same time but animate the movement itself.

Following is a very quick example solution which is mostly done in code (a map view and a button are in storyboard) so you can use it as a reference but will need some extra work...

```
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func dropPinsPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = (0..<50).map { _ in
            let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(Int(arc4random())%1000)/1000.0 * view.bounds.size.width, y: CGFloat(Int(arc4random())%1000)/1000.0 * view.bounds.size.height)
            return mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        }
        let anotations = coordinates.map { Annotation(coordinate: $0) }
        let sorted = anotations.sorted { $0.coordinate.longitude < $1.coordinate.longitude }
        let duration: TimeInterval = 2.0 // overall animation duration
        let durationFragment = duration/TimeInterval(sorted.count) // Duration between 2 drops

        sorted.enumerated().forEach { $1.delay = durationFragment*TimeInterval($0) }

        mapView.addAnnotations(sorted)
    }

}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        return PinView(animateDropFrom: view.frame.size.height, delay: (annotation as? Annotation)?.delay ?? 0.0)
    }

}

fileprivate extension ViewController  {

    class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        var delay: TimeInterval = 0.0

        init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.coordinate = coordinate
        }
    }

}

fileprivate extension ViewController  {

    class PinView: MKAnnotationView {

        lazy var pinView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.addSubview(view)
            return view
        }()

        convenience init(animateDropFrom height: CGFloat, delay: TimeInterval) {
            self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 20.0))

            pinView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y-height, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: { 
                self.pinView.frame = self.bounds
            }, completion: nil)
        }

    }

}
```

Next to design the biggest problem here is that the pin being dropped will drop again if you scroll off the current map and then back. Since `Annotation` is custom subclass you should probably just add the vertical offset into that class. Then when you first animate it reset the offset to zero it will not animate it again. Unless this is your expected behavior...